# Large $x$ expansion of $\ln \frac{1+e^{ax}}{1+e^{-bx}}$

Tags: asymptotics, approximation

When $x$ is very large, the following expression (with $a>0$, $b>0$)
$$\ln \frac{1+e^{ax}}{1+e^{-bx}}$$
Can be approximated using
$$1+e^{ax}\approx e^{ax}$$
$$1+e^{-bx}\approx 1$$
Therefore
$$\ln \frac{1+e^{ax}}{1+e^{-bx}}\approx \ln e^{ax}=ax$$
This is the leading term. How I can get the next term in the approximation?
I mean
$$\ln \frac{1+e^{ax}}{1+e^{-bx}}\approx  ax +c+\frac{c_1}{x}+\dots$$
I want to know $c$.

Comment: In the last line, note that the given function is not analytic at $\infty$; in fact, $\log(1 + e^{ax}) - ax = \log(1 + e^{-ax}) = o(x^{-n})$ as $x\to\infty$ for all $n \geq 0$.

Comment: No offense intended, but since you call yourself a "physics teacher", how come you are unable to perform this fairly elementary calculation?

Comment: @M.Wind It was not elementary for me. Why do not you try to help me with this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716380/using-the-saddle-point-method-or-laplace-method-for-a-multiple-integral-over-a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left[\log\left(\frac{1+e^{ax}}{1+e^{-bx}}\right)-ax\right]=\log\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{1+e^{-ax}}{1+e^{-bx}}=0 $$
gives $c=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln(1+e^{ax})-\ln(1+e^{-bx)})-ax=\ln(1+e^{-ax})-\ln(1+e^{-bx)})\approx e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}.$$

This function is very quickly decreasing and the coefficients of its Laurent series are null.

Comment: I don't know why I used binomial expansion!

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\ln \left(\frac{1+e^{ax}}{1+e^{-bx}}\right)=\ln\left(1+e^{ax}\right)-\ln\left(1+e^{-bx}\right)=$$
$$=\ln e^{ax}+\ln\left(1+e^{-ax}\right)-\ln\left(1+e^{-bx}\right)=$$
$$= ax+e^{-ax}+o(e^{-ax})-e^{-bx}+o(e^{-bx})$$

therefore we have $c=0$ and also $c_1=0$.